# Quantifiers Kenneth Rosen Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Please help me in regard with this question.I didn't have a clue how to solve this.

The way I thought about this question is assuming the truth values of predicates P(x) and Q(x) and then trying different combinations.

> Determine whether following propositions are equivalent. Justify your
>   answers.
>
> 1. ∀x (P(x) → Q(x)) and ∀x (P(x)) → ∀x (Q(x)).
> 2. ∀x (P(x) ⇔ Q(x)) and ∀x (P(x)) ⇔ ∀x (Q(x)).

Please provide a logical approach, not a mathematical approach.
Thank You.

Comment: Think about what the statements mean. For 1: the first statement means "All P's are Q's." The second means "If everything is P, then everything is Q." It should be fairly obvious these aren't equivalent. You can prove as much by exhibiting a countermodel. Take the universe $\left\{1,2\right\}$ with $P=\left\{1\right\}$, $Q=\emptyset$. Then the second statement is true but the first is false.

Comment: Doesn't the first statement means "For every x, if P(x) then Q(x)" and second statement means " If for every x P(x) the for every x Q(x) ".
Your first statement is confusing me.@symplectomorphic

Comment: "All P's are Q's" is just an informal way of saying "For every $x$, if $P(x)$ then $Q(x)$." This just means that if something is P (i.e. has property P), then it's Q (i.e. has property Q).

Comment: Ok thnx @symplectomorphic

Answer (score 1):

The first proposition in the first question says:

> Any $x$ in the universe of discourse that has property $P$ also has property $Q$.

The second says:

> If every $x$ in the universe of discourse has property $P$, then every $x$ in the universe of discourse has property $Q$.

To see whether two propositions are equivalent, it’s often helpful to ask under what circumstances each of them would be *false*. The first one would be false if there were some $x$ that had property $P$ but not property $Q$. The second would be false only if *every* $x$ had property $P$, but *not* every $x$ had property $Q$. It’s pretty clear that these are different requirements. Imagine that the universe of discourse contains just two objects, $a$ and $b$. Object $a$ has property $P$, object $b$ does not have property $P$, and neither $a$ nor $b$ has property $Q$. In this tiny system the first proposition is false, because $P(a)$ is true and $Q(a)$ isn’t. The second proposition, however, is true, because it’s an implication whose antecedent, $\forall xP(x)$, is false. (Remember that $p\to q$ is always true when $p$ is false.)

If you want a more ‘natural’ example, let the domain of discourse be the positive integers, let $P(x)$ be ‘$x$ is odd’, and let $Q(x)$ be ‘$x$ is prime’. In this model the first statement is false, since $15$ is odd but not prime. The second, however, is *vacuously true*: it says that ***if*** every positive integer is odd, then every positive integer is prime, and since it’s certainly not the case that every positive integer is odd, the proposition is automatically true. (If you’re at all bothered by this, ask yourself what evidence would be required to demonstrate conclusively that the implication was false: you’d need to show that even though every positive integer was odd, there was some composite positive integer. Since you can’t even show that every positive integer is odd (since it’s not true), you certainly can’t show that every positive integer is odd ***and*** some positive integer is composite.)

Now let’s look at the second question. The first proposition says:

> No matter what $x$ you consider in the universe of discourse, it has property $P$ if and only if it has property $Q$. Equivalently, every object in the universe of discourse either has both properties $P$ and $Q$, or neither.

The second says:

> Everything in the universe of discourse has property $P$ if and only if everything in the universe of discourse has property $Q$. That is, either everything in the universe of discourse has both properties $P$ and $Q$, or there is some object in the universe of discourse that does not have $P$ and some (possibly different) object that does not have $Q$.

Suppose that the first proposition is true. There are two cases to consider: either every $x$ in the universe of discourse has property $P$, or there is at least one that does not. In the first case the truth of the proposition means that every $x$ in the universe of discourse also has property $Q$. Thus, every object in the universe of discourse has both properties, as asserted by the second proposition. In the second case there is at at least one object that does not have $P$, and the truth of the first proposition ensures that it also fails to have $Q$. Thus, $\forall x(P(x))$ and $\forall x(Q(x))$ are both false, a situation that is also consistent with the truth of the second proposition. In short, if the first proposition is true, so is the second:

$$\forall x(P(x)\leftrightarrow Q(x))\;\to\;\big(\forall x(P(x)\leftrightarrow Q(x))\big)\;.$$

But the second proposition can be true even if the first is false. Suppose that our universe of discourse contains just two people: Tripta, who is female and single, and Bhushan, who is male and married. Let $P(x)$ be ‘$x$ is female’, and let $Q(x)$ be ‘$x$ is married’. In this tiny model the first proposition is false: it says that each of these two people is female if and only if that person is married, and Bhushan is a counterexample: he is married and *not* female.

The second proposition, however, is true. It’s not the case that everyone in the universe of discourse is female, so $\forall xP(x)$ is false, and the second proposition then says that $\forall xQ(x)$ must be false as well. And indeed it is: Tripta is not married, i.e., $Q(\text{Tripta})$ is false.

Thus, the two propositions are not equivalent.

Comment: thnx @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @Navneet: You're welcome.